# Tesseract with limited words

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to recognize a limited set of words in Tesseract?

I need to recognize a set of words (around 200) and want tesseract correct some words to the closest matching ones. In order to do that, I've updated the language models with my words (eng.word-dawg and eng.freq-dawg) and increased the sensitivity by setting language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word and language_model_penalty_non_dict_word to large numbers (tried 0.9 and 1.0). However, this does not have any affect on the output.

I have a word (BENZOATE) which tesseract always recognize as UENZOATE. This is weird as I have BENZOATE in my dictionary.

Comment: Did you get the solution to your question? I am also looking for an answer.

Comment: No. I have moved on long time ago.. :(